# How to manage protractor to wait for a angular page load where the angular SPA is integrated into another angular app as iFrame

Tags: angularjs-directive, protractor, jasmine2.0

While executing e2e tests in protractor when we are using ignore.synchronization=true/ browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true) to handle waits is too slow when compared to browser.sleep(10000) to proceed to next step. How to address these kind of wait issues to make the script execution faster?

Comment: Here, the tool expects the element before the page load (or) element to be available for further action so using "browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true)" to slow down the tool.

Comment: did you mean `browser.waitforAngularEnabled(false)`? `ignore.synchronization=true/ browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true)` are opposites.